# Google Chrome disable screen ruler

Tags: google-chrome

Since the last update of Google Chrome, a screen ruler shows up when inspecting an element. Does anyone know how to disable this ruler?

Comment: I truly dislike this feature. I'm glad to see I'm not the only one.

Comment: The ruler is extremely obtrusive when it appears on top of elements that the developer is actively inspecting. Otherwise, it is fine.

Comment: Sometimes, I would like a way to turn the ruler on without having to inspect an element.

Comment: try ctrl+shift+M in inspect mode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible for the moment.

You need to wait Chrome 25 or use Canari.

https://plus.google.com/115203843155141445032/posts/771CKRcKYdM

Comment: Your operating system is not supported. For Windows XP, Vista, and 7

Comment: its for both: [win](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs?platform=win) [mac](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs?platform=mac)

Comment: they appeared again, in chrome 28, when you resize the windows and you have devtools open, the pain in the arse comes back... what's the point of this ***ddamn rulers?

Answer (score 41):

This is an old question, but now you can enable or disable now in `Chrome Developer Tools -> Settings -> Show Rulers` (you can also access the settings just pressing F1).

[image: How to enable or disable rulers in Chrome]

Comment: This option doesn't seem to do anything now on Chrome 28 mac.  Rulers will always display when resizing the area with devtools open.

Comment: @danronmoon They are useful in my opinion. They disappear a few seconds after finishing the resize.

Comment: I think this is something new, they were NOT always on when resizing earlier. I specialize in responsive web dev jobs and this started bothering me recently. In addition to covering some of the elements I need to see when resizing, it also adds a bit of lag to the resize process, probably due to ruler being rendered. It's probably useful to someone, but there SHOULD be an option to disable it, since the one in settings doesn't work on the on-resize ruler.

Comment: I filled this as an issue, feel free to comment/star it if this bothers you as well:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260637

Comment: when resizing you see the size of your current viewport. You only see this when you have devtools open. Is there an option to always make this visible aswell? When I have devtools closed?

Answer (score 26):

In Chrome 38, there is a "Toggle Device Mode" button to the left of menu items in developer tools. Clicking on it will toggle display of ruler and device emulation list.

[image: The Toggle Device Mode Button is the second from the left and highlights blue when active]

Comment: Same holds true for Chrome 39.

Comment: this comments helped to solve the issue for me. Looks like once you click the toggle device mode chrome remembers it for ever until you toggle it back

Answer (score 25):

Go to **"Settings" -> "General"** tab.

In the end of page, click on button **"Restore defaults and reload"**.
=)

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.  The "show hide ruler" checkbox in settings was doing nothing, but resetting got it working as expected.  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is now known as [Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode). It allows you to select different device screen sizes as well as emulate different Network Speeds.

You can enable/disable it by clicking the **Phone Icon** on your console.

Comment: I would have voted this up a hundred times if I were able. <3

Comment: I wish you were able to, that would do wonders for my reputation :) anyway glad it helped.

Comment: This showed me how to get rid of the rulers, unlike the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest dev release fixed this for me: 
http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html?dl=mac

Answer (score 0):

This started happening to me out of the blue. I use Chrome inspect element for developing, on a personal computer that no one else uses.

This morning, I had the whole rulers-and-menus thing appear as if out of nowhere.

The above suggestions did nothing. When I got to the configuration check-box for rulers, I discovered it was turned off.

I was able to get the old look back by resetting the defaults in the same config menu which held the rulers check-box. Hope that helps anyone stuck like I was.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the unspect editor opened, Just go to settings by clicking the icon (top right on the unspector)  there you will find a big button saying **restore defaults and reload** . That worked for me . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome Canary (Version 45.0.2451.0 canary), and the presence of the rulers appears to be tied to whether Emulation is enabled. Restoring defaults (as suggested above) turns it off, or you can just go to the drawer at the bottom and do it.